# HTML table to JSON using casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am converting `<tr>` to json and it is working fine except the amount key sometimes has negative value but the minus sign is added onto the webpage using `class="amount negative currency-eur"` so I can't read it along with the remaining text. Heres my code. What should I change to achieve that.?

```
casper.then(function () {

var info = this.evaluate(function () {
    var table_rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr"); //or better selector

    return Array.prototype.map.call(table_rows, function (tr) {
        return {
            Date: tr.children[2].textContent,

            Amount: tr.children[1].textContent,
            Description: tr.children[0].textContent
        };
    });
});

this.echo(JSON.stringify(trimObj(info), "\n", 4));
```